# Do Deligne and truncated De Rham cohomologies define a Bloch-Ogus cohomology in char $0$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology

In [Deligne
homology, Hodge D-conjecture
and motives](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/pschnei/publ/beilinson-volume/Jannsen.pdf), Jannsen shows that Deligne cohomology over varieties over a complex number is a Bloch-Ogus cohomology theory. How important is working over $\mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$? Is the algebraic Deligne cohomology over char $0$ not in general a Bloch-Ogus theory?

I have a similar question about the truncated algebraic De Rham cohomology i.e. $h^i(X,j)=\mathbb{H}^i(X, \tau^{\leq j}\Omega^{\bullet}_{alg})$. Is it a Bloch-Ogus cohomology theory in general over char $0$? If not how about $\mathbb{C}$? (Over $\mathbb{C}$ should be true). Here the truncation is the fine truncation.

Comment: First of all,  what do you mean by algebraic Deligne cohomology over a general characteristic zero field? Usually you take the cohomology of complex $\mathbb{Z}(j)\to \mathcal{O}_X\to\ldots$ in the analytic topology.

Comment: Everything in the complex seems to be definable in the algebraic setting. Differential forms should be algebraic forms. The coefficient of $2πi$ might be dropped.

Comment: Ok, but my point really is that the constant sheaf $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn’t have a good algebraic analogue. This touches on some  fairly deep questions, such as whether Hodge  cycles are absolute.